# Parameter not passing into SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, ado.net

I need help with this; seems straightforward but I just can't figure it out.

My code:

```
    public DataTable GetUserAssociatedModules(string UserEmail)
    {
        // retrieve module titles from Module table to be passed to ddlModules in Student.Master
        try
        {
            SqlCommand getModules = new SqlCommand("GetUserAssociatedModules", con);
            getModules.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userEmail", UserEmail);

            SqlDataReader dr;
            dr = getModules.ExecuteReader();

            //DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("moduleTitle");
            dt.Load(dr);
            return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Exception: " + ex.Message + ", CourseDAO.GetModules()");
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            // close database connection
            if (con != null)
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

I keep getting an exception:

> *Procedure or function 'GetUserAssociatedModules' expects parameter '@userEmail', which was not supplied.*

I put a a watch on `UserEmail`; it's passing the value down from the UI as it should but the datareader remains null...

I've checked my SQL; it executes OK.

I've double and triple checked to ensure stored procedure name called in code matches the procedure in the database and that the parameter name in the code matches the one in the procedure...

The procedure...

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetUserAssociatedModules]
    @userEmail nvarchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        [dbo].[Module].[moduleId],[moduleTitle] 
    FROM 
        [dbo].[Module] 
    INNER JOIN 
        [dbo].[ModuleUser] ON [dbo].[Module].[moduleId] = [dbo].[ModuleUser].[moduleId]
    WHERE 
        [dbo].[ModuleUser].[userId] = (SELECT [userId]
                                       FROM [dbo].[User]
                                       WHERE [eMail] = @userEmail)
    ORDER BY 
        [moduleTitle] ASC
END
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing either opening the connection:

**conn.Open();**

Or not specifying this line:

**sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;**

```
public DataTable GetUserAssociatedModules(string userEmail)
{
var dt = new DataTable();
string connString = AppConfigurationManager.GetAppSetting("ConnectionString",IsTest,IsQA, IsProd);
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("GetUserAssociatedModules", conn))
    {
        sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userEmail", userEmail);

        SqlDataReader dr = null;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            dr = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
            dt = new DataTable("DatatTable_GetUserAssociatedModules");
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            ds.Load(dr, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges, dt);
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            LogExceptions(ex, new List<Param> { new Param { Name = "userEmail", Value = userEmail} });
         }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogExceptions(ex, new List<Param> { new Param { Name = "userEmail", Value = userEmail} });
        }
        finally
        {

        }
    }
}
return dt;
}
```

Comment: you left out a lot more than that user1748443

Comment: Damn dude, its the end of a long day and my brain just could not figure this one out. I had left off the commandtype. You spared me lol